# What exactly is touching the DOM?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am currently trying to implement Angular Universal in my app, but I have a lot of manipulations in my app. 
I do not completely understand what touching the DOM actually is.

Is changing the text inside a div using jquery touching the DOM?

Having a button scroll to the bottom?

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#sectAbout").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Adding a class?:

```
$('#smallLogo').addClass(this.diffAni[picked]);
```

having an image rotate?

Listening for scroll events?:

```
$(document).scroll(function() { 
scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
```

etc.
Can you give some examples of what touching the DOM actually means and/or some clear signs of touching the DOM?
Also is there any way to test an app without allowing it to touch the DOM?

Some alternatives would be helpful. I know adding a class is really simple with just using ngClass, but how about the scroll events?

Comment: All of these touching the DOM

Comment: Yeah, I kind of figured, JQuery was meant to manipulate the dom, but I wanted to know how something like scrolling is touching the DOM and a replacement

Comment: Touching/binding != manipulating. What you want to know?

Comment: Please clarify, is your question about angularjs or angular2?

Comment: Angular 2 sorry, I will update the tags

Comment: Touching the DOM means querying for DOM elements or manipulating them in any way. The only way than is not "touching the DOM" directly is manipulation by using Angular directives like `*ngFor` or bindings `{{xxx}}` or using the `Renderer`.

Comment: I updated the tags, this is more so a Angular Universal question, because it does not allow you to touch the DOM, and that's where my questions are based off of

Comment: Yeah, NgFor, NgClass, data binding, etc are really great alternatives.
But how about scrolling specifically? or rotating an image periodically?

Comment: You can use all the goodness of JavaScript. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Comment: What answer do you expect, so I will write one.